# Problem while building a .dll (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll

I am trying to build a .dll in order to link it to one of my projects. But the build always fails : I got these messages in the output and I don't know what it means. It seems that something is missing, but I couldn't find what.

I am trying to link a Mesher called Netgen
http://www.hpfem.jku.at/netgen/

`1>adfront2.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification 
 
1>   Creating library D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\converter/lib\nglib.lib and object D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\converter/lib\nglib.exp 
 
1>Embedding manifest... 
 
1>Performing Post-Build Event... 
 
1>Environment variable NETGENDIR not found.... using default location!!! 
 
1>POSTBUILD Script for nglib ........ 
 
1>Installing required files into XXX\Netgen\windows....\nglib-instNoOCC_Win32 .... 
 
1>File not found - nglib.dll 
 
1>0 File(s) copied 
 
1>POSTBUILD Script for nglib FAILED..... Error copying the nglib DLL into install folder!!! 


1>Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 1 returned from 'C:\Windows\SysWow64\cmd.exe'.

1>Build log was saved at "file://D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\converter\BuildLog_nglib.htm"

1>nglib - 1 error(s), 49 warning(s)`

I hope I am clear enough and thank you by advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems this NetGen lib's project wants to run a post-build event in which it tries to copy the main output (the nglib.dll) to the directory NETGENDIR (which is supposed to be an environment variable). This fails beccuse the dll isn't found.
Either disable the post build event, or check with the NetGen lib's creator what they expect here, there seems to be a mismatch between the project's output dir and the postbuild event.
Would also be nice to see the postbuild event from the vcproj file, maybe you can post it?

Comment: In fact, I had modified the output folder. this explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need read, by example the output line:

> 1>Environment variable NETGENDIR not found.... using default location!!!

After that I suggest that you must read the documentation about how define a enviroment variable named: **NETGENDIR**